# Lebesgue integral equals Riemann Integral on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

I know that if a function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann Integrable  then it is Lebesgue Integrable there with respect to the lebesgue measure and the integrals coincide.
Does this theorem also apply to improper Riemann integrability on unbounded intervals of the real line e.g. over $\mathbb{R}=(-\infty,\infty)$ itself?

Comment: No because the Riemann integral is usually not defined on the line and can only be interpreted as a limit of Riemann integrals on increasingly large intervals $[a_,n,b_n]$. One cannot divide an unbounded interval into finitely many intervals of finite length/.

Comment: I meant improperly Riemann Integrable, sorry

Comment: Okay - there are functions whose improper Riemann integral exists but Lebesgue integral does not exist. These are functions which are not *absolutely integrable*, instead the integral only converges due to convenient cancellations between positive and negative values. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. remember that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable if and only of $|f|$ is Lebesgue integrable. But this isn't true for Riemann (improper) integrability.

So theere may exists functions that are Riemann (improper) integrable but such that its absolute value is not integrable. The classical example is $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ over $(0,+\infty)$.

It can be shown that $\int_0^{+\infty}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ converges but $\int_0^{+\infty}\dfrac{|\sin x|}{x}$ diverges. It is known as [Dirichlet Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral)).

One can see this function as the equivalent to the alternating Harmonic series.

Comment: What if $f$ is odd function?

Comment: You mean an odd function over $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Yes. As in $f(-x) = -f(x)$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: You cannot take $\lim_{b\to+\infty}\int_{-b}^b f(x)dx$. That would be the PRINCIPAL CAUCHY VALUE. Remember that for improper integrals you should divide: $\lim_{b\to-\infty}\int_{b}^0+\lim_{a\to+\infty}\int_0^a$.

Comment: Thank you I had never heard of that. If I used the two different limits as you said then for the odd function over $\mathbb{R}$ does that make sense to says to lebesgue integral is equal to the sum of those two improper integrals?